# How to optimize the code to make the setup faster

Tags: graphics, installation, runtime, delay, netlogo

I am facing a problem in terms of setup time. I have created a model where patches are highlighted using the following code:

```
ask patches [set pcolor scale-color gray proportion 0 max-value ]
```

I also have a switch whose purpose when true to is to do the following:

```
ask patches [ if switch? [set pcolor [color] of closest-turtle ]]
```

Every time i press the setup/go buttons in the interface it is very slow. I initially thought it might be due to the complexity of the model and checked for it but doesn't seem to be the case. It's being more likely due to the switch and so removed the switch and just went with the below setup but it still is causing a delay

```
ask patches [ set pcolor [color] of closest-turtle ]
```

Is there a way to get around this. I currently have to save the model, close it and open it again every-time i make a change.

Thanks in advance, appreciate the help!!

Below is my complete code:

```
breed [ parties party ]

globals [
  total-votes
  max-voteshare
  largest-party
  ]

parties-own [
  my-size
  my-old-size
  my-rule
  my-benefit
  my-benefit-chen
  ]

patches-own [
  votes  
  vote-share
  closest-party
  closest-party-dist
  nearest-neighbors
  nearest-neighbors-dist
  b
  farthest-party
  farthest-party-dist
  b-c
  f
  h
  votes-with-benefit
  ]

;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;

to setup
  clear-all
  reset-ticks
  create-voters
  setup-parties
  update-support
  ;update-voter-totals
  setup-plot

end

;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;

to create-voters
  ask patches [       
      let x1 (pxcor - pop1-econ-mean) / sd-pop1
      let y1 (pycor - pop1-soc-mean) / sd-pop1     
      ;;set votes (voter-population / 2) * (red-size) * exp (-0.5 * ( x1 ^ 2 + y1 ^ 2)) / (2 * pi * sd-red ^ 2)
      set votes ( (pop1) * exp (-0.5 * ( x1 ^ 2 + y1 ^ 2)) / (2 * pi * sd-pop1 ^ 2) )

      let x2 (pxcor - pop2-econ-mean) / sd-pop2
      let y2 (pycor - pop2-soc-mean) / sd-pop2     
      ;set votes (votes) + (voter-population / 2) * (blue-size) * exp (-0.5 * ( x2 ^ 2 + y2 ^ 2)) / (2 * pi * sd-blue ^ 2) ]
      set votes ((votes) + ( (pop2) * exp (-0.5 * ( x2 ^ 2 + y2 ^ 2)) / (2 * pi * sd-pop2 ^ 2) ))

      set votes-with-benefit votes
  ]


 set total-votes sum [ votes-with-benefit ] of patches

  print (word "Max votes at one point = " precision (max[votes] of patches) 2)
  print (word "Min vote at one point = " precision (min[votes] of patches) 2)
  print (word "Max votes at one point = " precision (max[votes-with-benefit] of patches) 2)
  print (word "Min vote at one point = " precision (min[votes-with-benefit] of patches) 2)
  print (word "Total votes = " round(total-votes))     


 ask patches [set vote-share (votes-with-benefit / total-votes)]

  set max-voteshare (max[vote-share] of patches)

  ask patches [set pcolor scale-color gray vote-share 0 max-voteshare ] 

end

;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;

to setup-parties
  create-parties 1 [set color red set label-color red set label who + 1 set size 3 setxy party1-left-right party1-lib-con ]
  create-parties 1 [set color green set label-color red set label who + 1 set size 3 setxy party2-left-right party2-lib-con ]
  if Num-of-parties >= 3
  [ create-parties 1 [set color blue set label-color red set label who + 1 set size 3 setxy party3-left-right party3-lib-con ] ]
  if Num-of-parties >= 4
  [ create-parties 1 [set color orange set label-color red set label who + 1 set size 3 setxy party4-left-right party4-lib-con ] ]
  if Num-of-parties >= 5
  [  create-parties 1 [set color brown set label-color red set label who + 1 set size 3 setxy party5-left-right party5-lib-con ] ]
  if Num-of-parties >= 6
  [ create-parties 1 [set color yellow set label-color red set label who + 1 set size 3 setxy party6-left-right party6-lib-con ] ]
  if Num-of-parties >= 7
  [ create-parties 1 [set color lime set label-color red set label who + 1 set size 3 setxy party7-left-right party7-lib-con ] ]
  if Num-of-parties >= 8
  [ create-parties 1 [set color turquoise set label-color red set label "8" set size 3 setxy party8-left-right party8-lib-con ] ]
  if Num-of-parties >= 9
  [ create-parties 1 [set color cyan set label-color red set label who + 1 set size 3 setxy party9-left-right party9-lib-con ] ]
  if Num-of-parties >= 10
  [ create-parties 1 [set color magenta set label-color red set label who + 1 set size 3 setxy party10-left-right party10-lib-con ] ]

  ask parties [ update-rule set my-old-size 1 set shape "default" set heading random-float 360]

end

;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;

to update-support

  ask patches [ set closest-party min-one-of parties [distance myself]
                set closest-party-dist [distance myself] of closest-party
                set farthest-party max-one-of parties [distance myself]
                set farthest-party-dist [distance myself] of farthest-party

   set f ( -1 / ([my-old-size] of closest-party / total-votes) ) * (closest-party-dist + 0.0000000001)
  set h ([my-old-size] of farthest-party / total-votes) * (farthest-party-dist ^ 2)

  set b-c (f + h)

  ]

  ask parties [set my-size sum [votes-with-benefit] of patches with [closest-party = myself]
    set my-benefit mean[b] of patches with [closest-party = myself]
    set my-benefit-chen mean[b-c] of patches with [closest-party = myself]
  ]

  ask patches with [votes-with-benefit > 0.001] [ ifelse (b-c <= threshold) 
    [ set votes-with-benefit 0 set pcolor black ]
    [set votes-with-benefit votes 
      set pcolor [color] of min-one-of parties [distance myself]
      ] 
    ]  

  set largest-party max-one-of parties [my-size]

  ;ask patches with [votes-with-benefit >= 0.001] [ set pcolor [color] of closest-party ] 
  ;ask patches [ set pcolor [color] of closest-party ] 
  ;ask patches [set pcolor [color] of min-one-of turtles [distance myself]]

end


;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
to update-rule
  ask turtle 0 [set my-rule party1-rule ]
  ask turtle 1 [set my-rule party2-rule ]
  if Num-of-parties >= 3
    [ ask turtle 2 [set my-rule party3-rule ] ]
    if Num-of-parties >= 4
    [ ask turtle 3 [set my-rule party4-rule ] ]
    if Num-of-parties >= 5
    [ ask turtle 4 [set my-rule party5-rule ] ]
    if Num-of-parties >= 6
    [ ask turtle 5 [set my-rule party6-rule ] ]
    if Num-of-parties >= 7
    [ ask turtle 6 [set my-rule party7-rule ] ]
    if Num-of-parties >= 8
    [ ask turtle 7 [set my-rule party8-rule ] ]
    if Num-of-parties >= 9
    [ ask turtle 8 [set my-rule party9-rule ] ]
    if Num-of-parties >= 10
    [ ask turtle 9 [set my-rule party10-rule ] ]

end 

;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;

to adapt
  if (my-rule = "hunter") [hunt]
  if (my-rule = "aggregator") [aggregate]
  if (my-rule = "predator") [prey]

end


to hunt                 
  ifelse (my-size > my-old-size) [jump 1] [set heading heading + 90 + random-float 180 jump 1]
  ;set my-old-size my-size 

end

to aggregate
   if (my-size > 0) 
   [
     set xcor (sum [votes * pxcor] of patches with [closest-party = myself] / my-size)
     set ycor (sum [votes * pycor] of patches with [closest-party = myself] / my-size)
   ]
end

to prey
  if (my-size < [my-size] of largest-party) [face largest-party jump 1]
end

;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;

to intermediate-steps
  ask parties [adapt] 
  update-support
  ask turtles [ set my-old-size my-size]

end

;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;

to setup-plot
    set-current-plot "Voter Turnout"
    ;set-current-plot "Voter Benefit"
    set-current-plot "Distribution of benefit across voters"
end

to update-turnout-plot
  set-current-plot "Voter Turnout"
  set-current-plot-pen "Party1" 
  plot 100 * [my-size] of turtle 0 / total-votes
  set-current-plot-pen "Party2"
  plot 100 * [my-size] of turtle 1 / total-votes
  if Num-of-parties >= 3 [ set-current-plot-pen "Party3"
  plot 100 * [my-size] of turtle 2 / total-votes ]
  if Num-of-parties >= 4 [ set-current-plot-pen "Party4"
  plot 100 * [my-size] of turtle 3 / total-votes ]
  if Num-of-parties >= 5 [set-current-plot-pen "Party5"
  plot 100 * [my-size] of turtle 4 / total-votes]
  if Num-of-parties >= 6 [set-current-plot-pen "Party6"
  plot 100 * [my-size] of turtle 5 / total-votes]
  if Num-of-parties >= 7 [set-current-plot-pen "Party7"
  plot 100 * [my-size] of turtle 6 / total-votes]
  if Num-of-parties >= 8 [set-current-plot-pen "Party8"
  plot 100 * [my-size] of turtle 7 / total-votes]
  if Num-of-parties >= 9 [set-current-plot-pen "Party9"
  plot 100 * [my-size] of turtle 8 / total-votes]
  if Num-of-parties >= 10 [set-current-plot-pen "Party10"
  plot 100 * [my-size] of turtle 9 / total-votes]

end

to update-b-chen
  set-current-plot "Distribution of benefit across voters"
  set-current-plot-pen "patches"
  histogram [b-c] of patches
end


to go
  intermediate-steps
  update-turnout-plot
  update-b-chen

  tick

end
```

Comment: unless you have an inordinate number of patches the problem is probably in your procedure closest-turtle. what does it look like?

Comment: @King-Ink I don't think that's the problem because when i created the base model it was still fast with 10 turtles and 35 x 35 patch grid. Nonetheless the code i used for closest-turtle is 
'ask patches [ set closest-turtle min-one-of turtles [distance myself] ] '

Comment: That doesn't seem bad . how many turtles do you have now?

Comment: @King-Ink i have kept the number of turtles dynamic using a slider, it is a user defined value. Maximum is 10. I don't think that's the problem. I have added new procedures stepwise and thereby built the complexity only after ensuring everything works fine at each step. So i didn't face this delay problem until the graphic section that i have mentioned above.

Comment: I just tried "ask patches [set pcolor [color] of min-one-of turtles [distance myself]]" with 100x100 and 1000 turtles to see if I could duplicate  the problem. Unfortunately, it was not slow.

Comment: What kind of system are you using, i have 8gb RAM.

Comment: It sounds like you are asking 35x35 patches each to look at 10 turtles to see which is closest.  That means that you are checking 35*35*10=12250 distances, taking the minimum of 10 distances 1225 times.  Maybe that's a lot of computation on a slower machine?  (On the other hand, I agree this sounds like the sort of thing one does all the time in NetLogo without a noticeable delay, even on slower machines.)  If that  *is* the problem, I can imagine more efficient methods that are more complicated.

Comment: Yuvaraj, you said were using 35x35 initially (when it was fast), how many do you have? If its still 35x35 (or anything less than, say, 1000x1000), can you post your full `setup` code? Something else is going on here.

Comment: So you are asking patches to find closest-turtle, but it appears that procedure also asks patches. If so, you have nested asks and with 35x35 world, you have 1225x1225 asks.

Comment: It's still 35x35. I haven't changed that. But what i do have is other sub-routines for both the turtles and patches. Each patch has to calculate its closes turtle in each tick because the turtles keep moving and also the patches have to measure other metrics based on which the turtles move. So ya i am sorry for not posting the complete situation. Should i post the entire code?

Comment: "Should i post the entire code?"

Yes please. I don't see any problems with what you've posted so far.

Comment: I have added the full code. Please do let me know what's causing the problem.

Comment: One way to optimize would be in your if num-of-parties > = X section, change it to "IF AND" statements. Right now if you have 10 parties, it's going to run the code for if you had 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 and 10 but I'm guessing you just want it to do if it has 10 (I could be wrong). ex. if num-of-parties >= 2 AND != 1 [do stuff]

Unless you want the whole sequence that is

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bit after the fact but, in addition to the comments already posted, your switch code is a bit inefficient and could be optimized.

```
ask patches [ if switch? [set pcolor [color] of closest-turtle ]]
```

This tells every patch to check if the switch is on, then to make a decision. A more efficient way to code this would be:

```
if switch? TRUE [ask patches[set pcolor [color] of closest-turtle]]
```

This tells the observer to check the switch once (instead of once per patch) then tell the patches to do stuff. Not the full efficiency issue, but part of it